# How do you derive the adjectival form of an irregular verb such as "read"?

Tags: adjectives, participles, derivational-morphology, irregular-verbs

If I understand correctly, some adjectives can be derived from verbs.

For example, an **interested** person is someone who is interested in me, and an **interesting** person is someone who is interesting to me.

So how you do it with irregular verbs?

In the phrase "do something with data which was read" could the "data which was read" be replaced with something like "the **read** or **readed** data"?

I'm confused by fact that this verb irregular and is spelled the same in 1-3 forms.

Comment: What about "the data read into the system is . . ."?

Answer (score 5):

The difference here comes in pronunciation, you would still use 'read' but speak is such as *red* or *reed* depending on the circumstance. For instance:

- I can *reed*.
- I *red* it.

Though, you could alter the sentence to replace 'read' with a couple of things, as per @Martin's comment 'entered' or 'loaded' could be used:

> We do something with the loaded data.
>
> We do something with the entered data.
>
> We do something with the provided data.

Or it could be shortened, but this is depending on context:

> We process the input.

Comment: might be clearer to replace it with "loaded" or "entered" - computer manuals aren't poetry

Comment: @Martin: You're correct, re-reading the question provoked more thought on the matter.

Comment: @Marting Beckett: thanks for very useful suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, we could "do something with the loaded" — but, dude, like, why harsh their mellow? This aggression will not stand, man.

Comment: @Robusto: I was actually puzzled for more than a moment there. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing obviously, you can't really say "readed data" - perhaps with more of the context we can come up with something better.

English isn't always as clear as languages that can do things with verb endings - that's why technical phrases can sound clumsy.

Comment: It's just a comment in source code - "do something with data which was read" - I wanted to rewrite its more cleaner and shortly

Comment: Thats fine - although 'input' or 'input data' could be better

Comment: Isn't the past of _read_ still _read_?

Comment: You can't say "readed data", but you can certainly say "read data" (pronounced "red", obviously). When a computer program is working its way through some data file, it's often convenient to speak of the *read* and the *unread data*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - but in a written comment 'read data' (instruction) and 'read data' (noun) are a bit confued

Comment: @Martin: however, that confusion does not exist in the constructions in question, "data which was read". It can only be parsed in exactly one way. There is no ambiguity whatsoever. Likewise, in OP's other example, "the read data", the presence of the article clearly rules out the imperative.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: Agree with RegDwight. Anyway, it's bordering on ridiculous that we should be discussing replacing this perfectly intelligible program code comment with something 'better' that even the likes of *us* can't quickly agree on. If I'd known OP's motivation originally, I'd have voted to close the question straight off.

Answer (score 2):

I think that technically "read data" is correct, but it sounds awkward (and appears even more awkward). To make it sound less awkward (without resorting to a different verb) you can add an adverb or change it into a phrasal verb:

- the data *read in*
- the *recently read* data
- *frequently read* data

I think that those are fine.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm confused by fact that this verb irregular and is spelled the same in 1-3 forms.

Exactly. Your readers will be confused too, if you write something like “examine the read data”.

Grammatically, *the read data* is fine. Practically, it is a confusing mess. Treat it as you would treat code that's technically correct but confusing: rewrite it.

For your amusement: Some other past participles that are exactly identical to the present tense are *bet*, *burst*, *cut*, *hit*, *hurt*, *let*, *put*, *run*, *set*, *shut*, and *split*. Some of these can be used before a noun (*some burst pipes*, *the hurt children*), but most aren’t normally used that way in practice (*the hit batter charged the mound* would be strange). *Read* is not alone, though it is especially bothersome for programmers.

**Workarounds:** An adjective or past participle with complements of its own can go *after* a noun: *the people hurt in the blast*, *the amount bet on the first race*, *batters hit by wild pitches*, *the data read from the socket*, *the data read so far*.

However, it is probably best to just drop the confusing word *read* and say *the data from the socket* or *all the input so far* or *the data in 'x'* where *x* is a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

here's [a list of about 370 irregular verbs](http://www.englishpage.com/irregularverbs/irregularverbs.html) and from what you're asking here's some adjectives:

***broken*** vase - from the infinitive **"break"**

***burnt*** toast - from the infinitve **"burn"**

***frostbitten*** fingers - from the infinitive **"frostbite"**

***lip-read*** movie - from the infinitive **"lip-read"**

***typewritten*** manuscript - from the infinitive **"typewrite"**

an so on and so forth, hope that helps! :)

Comment: thanks. I was asking because phrase "do something with read data" looks a bit ambiguously.

Comment: @bayda that's why I included "lip-read", there's also proofread in the list :) I think you have to pronounce read like "red" (the color)

Comment: Erm... *frostbitten* is the past participle of a somewhat 'notional' verb *to frostbite*, not some wildly irregular conjugation of *to freeze*. Though there are oddities such as *wrought iron*, which really is from the infinitive *to work*.

Comment: Not even frost is a participle, right? I looked it up to be sure, but it seems so...

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for pointing that out - I had several tabs opened haha I'll edit it :)